# How can I spawn multiple monsters in my game?

Tags: 2d, iphone, game-mechanics, objective-c

I made a little iPhone game in which I want to make multiple monsters spawn.

I have one UIImageView called `enemy` that spawns at beginning of the game. But I want it to spawn many more monsters until I say it needs to stop spawning them.

I know how to get random locations. This question is a follow up to [this one.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17381/how-can-i-spawn-monsters-at-random-locations)

Comment: I'm not sure but there sould be some timer class somewhere in iphone sdk

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a collection of monsters and a MAX_MONSTERS constant. I'm not much of an Objective-C programmer, but this pseudo-code should get you going:

```
.. top of program
MAX_MONSTERS = 5;
MonsterCollection[MAX_MONSTERS] mc;

... game loop
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_MONSTERS; i++)
    if(mc[i] != null && mc[i].IsAlive) 
        mc[i].Update();
    else
        mc[i] = // new monster
```

Comment: okay thank you but i mainly want to know how i can add more monsters like i have one uiimageview called enemy and i want to have 5 enemy's on screen but not declare everything 5 times

Comment: You can use an array, to declare one time, that you want a variable number of monsters. Otherwise you'll need to declare n different `UIImageView` objects, where n is the number of monsters you want.

Comment: so i need to create an array called monsters that stores as much variables as need and all those variables are the same UIImageView?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems like the `UIImageView` is holding your monster-graphics. The more important thing however is where you located the monster-logic (that will update/move the monster-graphics).

For multiple monsters, you'll need multiple instances of the `UIImageView`. Also you'll need to keep track of position and other properties (like health) for each monster. A reasonable approach to this would be to have a separate class that encapsulates all monster related logic.

Therefore, I suggest you create a special class (that inherits from `NSObject`) for monster and make the `UIImageView` a member of this class. A really basic interface for such a class could look like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Monster : NSObject {

}

@property(retain) UIImageView* view;

-(void) update:(double)dt;

@end
```

In the `init` method of your monster-class you would initialize your graphics (and assign it to  the `view` property). Creating multiple monsters can be done using something like this:

```
// constant that defines how many monsters should be created
#define NUM_MONSTERS 5

// monsters should be a member of your class, so that you can loop through it
// and perform updates. This is why we "retain" the monsters array here.
// You should use "release" to free the array in the class dealloc method.
NSMutableArray* monsters = 
    [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:NUM_MONSTERS] retain];

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MONSTERS; ++i){
    Monster* monster = [[Monster alloc] init];
    // store the monster in the monsters array
    [monsters addObject: monster];
    // add the monster view (UIImageView) to the current view 
    [self.view addSubview: monster.view];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at initWithNib method, if your views are designed in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: could you be a little more precisely please ?